# EntityNotFoundException (cannot evaluate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I mapped model like this:

```
    @Entity
    public class Notification {

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="ad")
        @Where(clause="is_deleted <> '1'")
        @JsonIgnore
        public Ad getAd() {
            return ad;
        }

    }
```

When Hibernate try to get this ad, it shows error:

```
Method threw 'javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException' exception.
Cannot evaluate Ad_$$_javassist_1.toString()
```

Comment: Please, add a full stack trace, use `code` to add it. And, please, add your Hibernate configuration and a Hibernate version.

Comment: Do you have `Ad` mapped with hibernate as well? Show the code for thst class

Comment: Ad mapped as hibernate. But this is one direction mapping of ManyToOne.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have any data in your table which you are trying to retrieve that is the cause of this exception.

First insert  record in your table than try to get the data there would not be any exception

Thank you
Chandan